# Microsoft Connected Cache cannot connect to and perform TLS handshake with iothub

Tags: caching, azure-iot-edge, mcc

We are setting up an MCC server, we have followed the instructions exactly from [the deployment guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/do/mcc-isp-create-provision-deploy) and all three docker images show as started:

```
root@or-ms-node1:~# iotedge list
NAME             STATUS           DESCRIPTION      Config
MCC              running          Up 2 minutes     msconnectedcacheprod1.azurecr.io/mcc/linux/iot/mcc-ubuntu-iot-amd64:1.2.1.1563
edgeAgent        running          Up 3 minutes     mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.4
edgeHub          running          Up 2 minutes     mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.4
root@or-ms-node1:~#
```

However, in the Azure Cache Node management the status stays as "never phoned home"

this is on a baremetal, blank Ubuntu 20 server. I have tried reinstalling the OS as well, and run in to the exact same issue. It is running on a public IP, in a DMZ.

Below are the connectivity errors it gets:

```
root@or-ms-node1:~# iotedge check --verbose

Configuration checks (aziot-identity-service)
---------------------------------------------
√ keyd configuration is well-formed - OK
√ certd configuration is well-formed - OK
√ tpmd configuration is well-formed - OK
√ identityd configuration is well-formed - OK
√ daemon configurations up-to-date with config.toml - OK
√ identityd config toml file specifies a valid hostname - OK
‼ aziot-identity-service package is up-to-date - Warning
    Installed aziot-identity-service package has version 1.4.2 but 1.4.4 is the latest stable version available.
    Please see https://aka.ms/aziot-update-runtime for update instructions.
        caused by: Installed aziot-identity-service package has version 1.4.2 but 1.4.4 is the latest stable version available.
                   Please see https://aka.ms/aziot-update-runtime for update instructions.
√ host time is close to reference time - OK
√ preloaded certificates are valid - OK
√ keyd is running - OK
√ certd is running - OK
√ identityd is running - OK
√ read all preloaded certificates from the Certificates Service - OK
√ read all preloaded key pairs from the Keys Service - OK
√ check all EST server URLs utilize HTTPS - OK
√ ensure all preloaded certificates match preloaded private keys with the same ID - OK

Connectivity checks (aziot-identity-service)
--------------------------------------------
‼ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with iothub AMQP port - Warning
    Could not retrieve iothub_hostname from provisioning file.
    Please specify the backing IoT Hub name using --iothub-hostname switch if you have that information.
    Since no hostname is provided, all hub connectivity tests will be skipped.
        caused by: Could not retrieve iothub_hostname from provisioning file.
                   Please specify the backing IoT Hub name using --iothub-hostname switch if you have that information.
                   Since no hostname is provided, all hub connectivity tests will be skipped.
‼ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with iothub HTTPS / WebSockets port - Warning
    Could not retrieve iothub_hostname from provisioning file.
    Please specify the backing IoT Hub name using --iothub-hostname switch if you have that information.
    Since no hostname is provided, all hub connectivity tests will be skipped.
        caused by: Could not retrieve iothub_hostname from provisioning file.
                   Please specify the backing IoT Hub name using --iothub-hostname switch if you have that information.
                   Since no hostname is provided, all hub connectivity tests will be skipped.
‼ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with iothub MQTT port - Warning
    Could not retrieve iothub_hostname from provisioning file.
    Please specify the backing IoT Hub name using --iothub-hostname switch if you have that information.
    Since no hostname is provided, all hub connectivity tests will be skipped.
        caused by: Could not retrieve iothub_hostname from provisioning file.
                   Please specify the backing IoT Hub name using --iothub-hostname switch if you have that information.
                   Since no hostname is provided, all hub connectivity tests will be skipped.
√ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with DPS endpoint - OK

Configuration checks
--------------------
√ aziot-edged configuration is well-formed - OK
√ configuration up-to-date with config.toml - OK
√ container engine is installed and functional - OK
√ configuration has correct URIs for daemon mgmt endpoint - OK
‼ aziot-edge package is up-to-date - Warning
    Installed IoT Edge daemon has version 1.4.8 but 1.4.10 is the latest stable version available.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-update-runtime for update instructions.
        caused by: Installed IoT Edge daemon has version 1.4.8 but 1.4.10 is the latest stable version available.
                   Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-update-runtime for update instructions.
√ container time is close to host time - OK
‼ DNS server - Warning
    Container engine is not configured with DNS server setting, which may impact connectivity to IoT Hub.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-prod-checklist-dns for best practices.
    You can ignore this warning if you are setting DNS server per module in the Edge deployment.
        caused by: Container engine is not configured with DNS server setting, which may impact connectivity to IoT Hub.
                   Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-prod-checklist-dns for best practices.
                   You can ignore this warning if you are setting DNS server per module in the Edge deployment.
√ production readiness: logs policy - OK
‼ production readiness: Edge Agent's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem - Warning
    The edgeAgent module is not configured to persist its /tmp/edgeAgent directory on the host filesystem.
    Data might be lost if the module is deleted or updated.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-storage-host for best practices.
        caused by: The edgeAgent module is not configured to persist its /tmp/edgeAgent directory on the host filesystem.
                   Data might be lost if the module is deleted or updated.
                   Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-storage-host for best practices.
‼ production readiness: Edge Hub's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem - Warning
    The edgeHub module is not configured to persist its /tmp/edgeHub directory on the host filesystem.
    Data might be lost if the module is deleted or updated.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-storage-host for best practices.
        caused by: The edgeHub module is not configured to persist its /tmp/edgeHub directory on the host filesystem.
                   Data might be lost if the module is deleted or updated.
                   Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-storage-host for best practices.
‼ Agent image is valid and can be pulled from upstream - Warning
    skipping because of previous failures
√ proxy settings are consistent in aziot-edged, aziot-identityd, moby daemon and config.toml - OK

Connectivity checks
-------------------
‼ container on the default network can connect to upstream AMQP port - Warning
    skipping because of previous failures
‼ container on the default network can connect to upstream HTTPS / WebSockets port - Warning
    skipping because of previous failures
‼ container on the default network can connect to upstream MQTT port - Warning
    skipping because of previous failures
‼ container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to upstream AMQP port - Warning
    skipping because of previous failures
‼ container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to upstream HTTPS / WebSockets port - Warning
    skipping because of previous failures
‼ container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to upstream MQTT port - Warning
    skipping because of previous failures
23 check(s) succeeded.
8 check(s) raised warnings.
7 check(s) were skipped due to errors from other checks.
root@or-ms-node1:~#
```

Comment: Does [setting the DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/troubleshoot-common-errors?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&view=iotedge-1.4#edge-agent-module-reports-empty-config-file-and-no-modules-start-on-the-device) for your container engine help?